# How do I update my random number value after one event?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So basically I need to update my random number value. It is z axis of position of target where object goes with lerp.

```
public Transform target;
public float time;

float randomNum = Random.Range(-40, 40);
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 a = transform.position;
    Vector3 b = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, randomNum);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, time);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update it, use:

```
randomNum = Random.Range(-40, 40);
```

Plus I guess you’ll want to reset `time`, and it looks to me as if `Vector3 a` should be a class variable that’s only updated when you change destination rather than a local variable? Unless you want the movement to start slow and get faster at least. (This is assuming `time` increases over time.)

Just mentioning that if your FixedTimeStep doesn’t match the user’s frame rate, updating movement in `FixedUpdate()` will cause movement to appear less smooth. The code that decides where to move might make sense in `FixedUpdate()` but the code that lerps between the positions might be better off in `Update()`.